# Cloudformation Ephemeral (Instance) Storage for instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I am trying to launch an EC2 Instance with CloudFormation that uses ephemeral / instance storage rather than EBS.

I have managed this with Opsworks - so that in the EC2 management window "root device" is not ebs.  I have yet to figure out how to do this with a CloudFormation template.

I have a feeling it has something to do with BlockDeviceMappings but have not figure it out yet.  Closest discussion to what I want to do I found here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=243921

Can someone supply a CloudFormation template snippet to launch a ephemeral storage based instance?

Other parts of the docs that seem useful:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what OS you are trying to launch, but the key is that you have to use the right AMI. For example, look at Canonical's AMI listings for Ubuntu:
http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

If you search for **precise us-east-1** you'll see there are 5 different AMIs:

```
us-east-1   precise 12.04 LTS   amd64   hvm             20130624    ami-25d9a94c    hvm
us-east-1   precise 12.04 LTS   amd64   ebs             20130624    ami-23d9a94a    aki-88aa75e1
us-east-1   precise 12.04 LTS   i386    ebs             20130624    ami-21d9a948    aki-b6aa75df
us-east-1   precise 12.04 LTS   amd64   instance-store  20130624    ami-d9d6a6b0    aki-88aa75e1
us-east-1   precise 12.04 LTS   i386    instance-store  20130624    ami-bfd3a3d6    aki-b6aa75df
```

The first one is for [cluster compute instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Does_use_of_Cluster_Compute_Instances_differ_from_other_Amazon_EC2_instance_types) only.

The second and third are for EBS-backed instances, 64bit or 32bit.

Finally, the fourth and fifth are for ephemeral / instance storage backed instances, 64bit or 32bit.

Once you have chosen an AMI that is instance-store backed, you can assign the rest of the emphemeral disks with this snippet inside the Properties:

```
"BlockDeviceMappings": [
    { "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb", "VirtualName": "ephemeral0" },
    { "DeviceName": "/dev/sdc", "VirtualName": "ephemeral1" },
    { "DeviceName": "/dev/sdd", "VirtualName": "ephemeral2" },
    { "DeviceName": "/dev/sde", "VirtualName": "ephemeral3" }
],
```

You may want to review the AWS [block device mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html) concepts page as well.

Comment: Your intuition was correct about precise 12.04.  A great answer, thank you for your time.